# How to discover XBee from Android and send data between the two

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, xbee, bluetooth-device-discovery

There are a number of threads regarding this topic, but I haven't been able to troubleshoot my issue yet and haven't seen much talk of using XBee-4 Nano. I am working on a Arduino/Android project where I need to have a remote XBee monitoring a button, once the button is pressed an notification is sent to my Android phone and I receive a message in the task bar saying the button was pressed.

I've been working on this for weeks... I've read many home automation book, walked through the XBee Lab manual, searched many forums, and installed the tools for Amarino. and the issue I'm having is not understanding how to get the XBee and Arduino to work enough to be discovered by . The Android portion I will be able to take care of.

The tools I have are

http://www.makershed.com/Xbee_Series_1_Starter_Kit_p/mkpx19.htm
(2) XBee 802.15.4 (Series 1) embedded-antenna modules.
(1) XBee USB Adapter for easy PC connection.
(1) XBee 5V/3.3V Adapter for microcontroller connection.

http://www.gravitech.us/xbadforarna.html
(2) XBee-4 Nano (shield for XBee and Arduino Nano)
(3) Arduino Nano
(1) Arduino Uno

X-CTU
Putty
Arduino IDE with Amarino
Android Phone

My ideal setup is connect configure XBee and Arduino Nano on the XBee-4 Nano shield to monitor a button, connect XBee/Arduino to Android phone, then on button press, phone receives a notification.

I am able to monitor the button and turn on LED on button press using the Adruino Nano. How do I sent this data from the Arduino to the XBee using XBee-4 Nano? Are the TX->RX and RX->TX already connected and the XBee will just broadcast the data, or do I need to manually set up jumpers to do this?

Next question is how do I discover the XBee module from my Android phone? I have successfully completed the Bluetooth chat project between my 2 XBee's. I have installed the Amarino on my phone, but when I have the XBee hooked up to either of the adaptors or XBee-4 Nano, I am unable to discover the xbee. Why is this? Is there something with the baud rate or other setting I need to update to be able to do the discovery? Is the issue with the adaptor I am using? There is power to the XBee since I can light up an LED using D05 = 1 and ground.

If you can point me in the right direction on how to use the XBee-4 Nano and how to discover the XBee from an Android phone (using Amarino), it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Are the TX->RX and RX->TX already connected

yes, just look at the schematics: http://site.gravitech.us/Arduino/XBEE-4NANO/Schematic.pdf

> how do I discover the XBee module from my Android phone?

What do you mean for "discover"?
if you mean when the xbee is plugged, you cant easily. xbee is transparent, they are like connecting cable directly. but they respond to come AT command, if i'm right, so you can try to use them (but probabily the BLUETOOTH card will respond), unless the request is done on the mini side, and only a specific signal is sent back to amarino.

Comment: Hi, thanks... schematic makes sense now. By "discover", I mean have it show up in the available to pair list when I try searching for nearby bluetooth devices on my phone. I've been trying to follow steps here http://www.elecfreaks.com/829.html but am stuck on step 6 where they say set to master mode? It sound like I shoule be able to type in a few AT commands and I should be able to find the xbee from my phone. I have the modem set to XB24 - Function Set: XBEE 802.15.4. Is there a problem with this?

Comment: Here are some screenshots of my issue. I'm trying to follow the steps provided in the url above and here is what i'm seeing: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ViV2sCMnMqc0ZCTGhuVjcwRU0/edit?usp=sharing